# how to extract information from a plot/graph in Internet explorer using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

```html
<body id="ctl00_Body1" class="pBack"><div class="tipsy tipsy-w" style="top: 3279.47px; left: 1096.63px; visibility: visible; display: block; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 100000;"><div class="tipsy-arrow tipsy-arrow-w"></div><div class="tipsy-inner">Mon Sep 03 2018<br>357,938 Units</div></div>
```

I'm pretty new to VBA programming as well as Web-scraping, so pardon me if my coding is little shabby.

**Project Detail**

I'm working on a project which involves scraping a website for multitude of data.

**What i Have Done so Far**

Currently i have managed to login to the website using username and password, enter a search parameter, click a button to show results. On the results i'm able to extract the data which are in tables. I have given below the code that i have developed so far.

**Problem Statement**

Now i need a information which is showing in a graph, the information is shown when i click on the plot point (i have enclosed screenshot/link of the graph along with the html code). I want to get the number before the units text. The link is internal to the company so i'm unable to share it

[image]

**This is the code that i have developed so far:**

```
Sub MultiCpn_Div_Class()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Active sheet where the search parameter will be
Dim rc As Long
'loop variable
Dim CPN As String
'search parameter from active sheet

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim HTMLTABL As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTABLC As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLDivc As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLDIV As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLROW As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLCELL As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Rownum, Colnum, Sheetnum As Long


MyURL = "XXXXXXXXX"

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
'Had to declare ie as Medium because it kept on failing if i didnt
'ie.Silent = True
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate MyURL
Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDOC = ie.document
HTMLDOC.all.ctl00_PageContent_UserName.Value = "username"
HTMLDOC.all.ctl00_PageContent_Password.Value = "password"
HTMLDOC.all.ctl00_PageContent_OKButton__Button.Click
'Providing user name, password and then signing in
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
rc = 2
'starting from second row of data
For rc = 2 To 5
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

CPN = Range("A" & rc).Value
'assigning cell value to variable
ie.navigate "YYYY"
'After logging in i had to navigate to a specific link-YYY otherwise it kept showing an error
   
Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set IEDOC = ie.document
'reassigned the HTML document to the newly loaded page
IEDOC.all.cpnval.Value = CPN
IEDOC.all.run_Button.Click
'entering the search parameter and then clicking the search button

Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
'had to include a wait for 2 seconds to cater to network delay issues

Set HTMLDOC = ie.document
 'again reassigned the HTML document to the newly loaded page which had all necessary data
Set HTMLDivc = HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("div")
'the page has multiple div classes inside which multiple tables are located, so getting a
'div collection and then looping over all tables data to search for particular tables that i want
   
For Each HTMLDIV In HTMLDivc
    
    If HTMLDIV.ID = "attributes_table" Then
        Set HTMLTABLC = HTMLDIV.Children
 
        For Each HTMLTABL In HTMLTABLC
            If HTMLTABL.className = "table table-striped temp" Then
                Sheets.Add.Name = "T1" & CPN
                Range("A1").Value = HTMLTABL.className
                Range("B1").Value = Now
                Rownum = 2
                'Once required table is found i'm copying that table data and pasting it into new sheet as required for each CPN

                For Each HTMLROW In HTMLTABL.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                Colnum = 1
         
                    For Each HTMLCELL In HTMLROW.Children
                    Cells(Rownum, Colnum) = HTMLCELL.innerText
                    Colnum = Colnum + 1
                    Next HTMLCELL
                    
                Rownum = Rownum + 1
                Next HTMLROW

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & rc).Value = Sheets("T1" & CPN).Range("B4")
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & rc).Value = Sheets("T1" & CPN).Range("B16")
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & rc).Value = Sheets("T1" & CPN).Range("B5")
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & rc).Value = Sheets("T1" & CPN).Range("B25")
            'After extracting the data to new sheet for each search parameter i'm copying that data and pasting into my active sheet
            End If
            
        Next HTMLTABL
        
    ElseIf HTMLDIV.ID = "award_table" Then
    'same as above creating new sheet for another table information
        Set HTMLTABLC = HTMLDIV.Children
        
        For Each HTMLTABL In HTMLTABLC
                If HTMLTABL.className = "table table-striped temp" Then
                    Sheets.Add.Name = "T2" & CPN
                    Range("A1").Value = HTMLTABL.className
                    Range("B1").Value = Now
                    Rownum = 2
        
                     For Each HTMLROW In HTMLTABL.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                     Colnum = 1
                     
                         For Each HTMLCELL In HTMLROW.Children
                         Cells(Rownum, Colnum) = HTMLCELL.innerText
                         Colnum = Colnum + 1
            
                         Next HTMLCELL
                         Rownum = Rownum + 1
            
                     Next HTMLROW
                     Dim i As Long
                     Dim sht As Worksheet
                     Dim LastRow As Long
                     Dim Moq, Moq2, Ven, Ven2 As Variant
                     Moq = ""
                     Ven = ""
                     Set sht = Sheets("T2" & CPN)
                     LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    
                            For i = 3 To LastRow
                                Moq2 = Sheets("T2" & CPN).Cells(i, 9).Value & vbCrLf
                                Moq = Moq + Moq2
                                Ven2 = Sheets("T2" & CPN).Cells(i, 1).Value & vbCrLf
                                Ven = Ven + Ven2
                            Next i
             
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & rc).Value = Moq
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & rc).Value = Ven
                              
                End If
        Next HTMLTABL
        
        Else
            If HTMLDIV.ID = "full_avl_table" Then
             'same as above creating new sheet for another table information
                Set HTMLTABLC = HTMLDIV.Children
                For Each HTMLTABL In HTMLTABLC
                    If HTMLTABL.className = "table table-striped temp" Then
                        Sheets.Add.Name = "T3" & CPN
                        Range("A1").Value = HTMLTABL.className
                        Range("B1").Value = Now
                        Rownum = 2
                
                         For Each HTMLROW In HTMLTABL.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                         Colnum = 1
                         
                             For Each HTMLCELL In HTMLROW.Children
                             Cells(Rownum, Colnum) = HTMLCELL.innerText
                             Colnum = Colnum + 1
                        
                             Next HTMLCELL
                             Rownum = Rownum + 1
                        
                         Next HTMLROW
                         Dim i2 As Long
                         Dim sht2 As Worksheet
                         Dim LR As Long
                         Dim AVL, AVL2 As Variant
                         AVL = ""
                         Set sht2 = Sheets("T3" & CPN)
                         LR = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                         For i2 = 3 To LR
                            Cells(i2, 7).Value = Cells(i2, 1) & " - " & Cells(i2, 2) & " - " & Cells(i2, 4) & " - " & Cells(i2, 6)
                            AVL2 = Sheets("T3" & CPN).Cells(i2, 7).Value & vbCrLf
                            AVL = AVL2 + AVL
                         Next i2

                        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & rc).Value = AVL
                        Columns("N").AutoFit
                                                    
                       End If
                Next HTMLTABL
            End If
    End If
    Next HTMLDIV

    Next
   ie.Quit
   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Close up Image of HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1juZ0.jpg)
**Update:** [Debug page snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/536Ia.jpg)

Comment: This may not matter but are you declaring ie anywhere?

Comment: Please can you share the HTML not as an image but using the snippet tool provided? Icon looks like a document with <> on it.

Comment: Could you share URL with us?

Comment: @JohnyL I'm afraid i cant share the URL, even if i did it wont be accessible on external network

Comment: @KySoto I didnt declare it but i guess it didnt matter for the running of the program

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to tell from that small image. See my comment re inserting HTML.

You might try, based on what I can see, the following:

```
Debug.Print Split(Split(HMLDoc.querySelector(".tipsy-inner").innerText, Chr(10))(1), Chr$(32))(0)
```

This bit, `querySelector(".tipsy-inner")`, targets by class the first element on the page with class name tipsy-inner. I then parse the `.innerText` on what I guess to be the delimiters present to try and split out the number part of the returned string.

If not found, you can try a timed loop to find:

```
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
Const WAIT_TIME_SECS As Long = 10

t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    If Timer - t > WAIT_TIME_SECS Then Exit Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = HMLDoc.querySelector(".tipsy-inner")
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop While ele Is Nothing

If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Debug.Print Split(Split(ele.innerText, Chr(10))(1), Chr$(32))(0)
```

Comment: i tried this and it is showing Run Time Error 424 - Object required. I have edited the post to show a much clearer image of the HTML Code.

Comment: hi, please copy the html and paste it in. When you edit your question there is a snippet tool (icon looks like a document with <> on. You then paste html in top left.). With html insert we can copy for testing.

Comment: Also, ensure there has been a wait before attempting to select e.g.  While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Comment: Hi QHarr, thanks for your quick response and sorry for not posting the html earlier, now i have added it. I'm not a software programmer per say so didn't get it the first time when you mentioned it. I did add a wait to the program but still getting the same error. I'm adding your code after these lines in the original code:        Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set HTMLDOC = ie.document

Comment: I have added a timed loop for you to try. From you html I can't see that your element is within a parent <form> or <frame> or <iframe> tag but can you also check for that please?

Comment: I just checked the code with the timer it doesnt give any error but it doesnt print anything in the immediate window too. I checked for parents and as you rightly pointed out the element is not under any form/frame/iframe tag. Just for added information, i see that for each point (small circle) on the graph when i click in the point and the popup comes up and then i do inspect element of that popup i get that above HTML snippet whereas in IE in mouse over i see the pop of the data point and i'm unable to inspect the element in IE)

Comment: hummm....... so it may be exiting the program as not set. If you press F8 to execute code line by line does the program exit at this line: If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Comment: Yup thats right but not on the first go, it loops through the statements under the If 3 times then on the fourth occasion it exits..

Comment: Huh? It shouldn't loop under that If at all if the object is not set. Are you sure it is getting past the  If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  line?

Comment: Sorry my bad.. i meant the If on the Timer loop not on the If ele is Nothing loop

Comment: If you increase Const WAIT_TIME_SECS As Long = 10
 does it make a difference?

Comment: I made the wait as 30 seconds still the same result, it doesn't print any information

Comment: Hello @QHarr, After lot of back and forth searching of the Webpage this is the latest that i have found. The dot on the graph/ plot displays the value by using a jquery. The jquery is in the form of a link and the responses for this link is what is shown in the plot (on mouseover / click). Now how can i parse the entire response from this link and extract only the last data(in total 25 data is shown, i want the 25th data)

Comment: I can't view that link. Can you [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) a link of the html for the document? And indicate what 25th data is? If when you inspect the page at that link and you right click on the html element you should have the option to copy element - that will copy the html for the page.

Comment: The HTMl document doesn't seem to hold that link or that data, it gets that data by calling a jquery. I checked this using Network tools option in the dev tools. I have added screenshot of that to my original question

Comment: Do you see a POST XHR request being made?

Comment: nothing like that on the HTML doc. when i see the plot on fireforx it shows an event tab next to the HTML code and the code is as follows:                                  function enter() {
  var tipsy = get(this);
  tipsy.hoverState = 'in';
  if (options.delayIn === 0) {
    tipsy.show();
  } else {
    tipsy.fixTitle();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (tipsy.hoverState == 'in') tipsy.show();
    }, options.delayIn);
  }
}

Comment: Hello QHarr, to provide you an update on this. I'm able to successfully use the code that i posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537836/parsing-xml-response-in-vba-and-extracting-only-last-data) to get the graph data and then parse the string from there. So my problem is fixed now..:-) Thank you so much for taking your time and trying to resolve this :-)

Comment: just saw this (sorry!) - thanks for letting me know :-)