# Parsing XML Response in VBA and extracting only last data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a XML request through excel vba for one of the internal links (in our company). when i send request and receive response using the code below, i get the following **as response text**:

```
[{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-04-02 
00:00:00","Demand":"8645"},"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-04-09 
00:00:00","Demand":"8985"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-04-16 
00:00:00","Demand":"9341"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-04-23 
00:00:00","Demand":"9589"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-04-30 
00:00:00","Demand":"9210"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-05-07 
00:00:00","Demand":"9698"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-05-14 
00:00:00","Demand":"9542"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-05-21 
00:00:00","Demand":"9692"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-05-28 
00:00:00","Demand":"10416"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-06-04 
00:00:00","Demand":"6777"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-06-11 
00:00:00","Demand":"12774"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-06-18 
00:00:00","Demand":"12912"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-06-25 
00:00:00","Demand":"12693"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-07-02 
00:00:00","Demand":"12895"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-07-09 
00:00:00","Demand":"13366"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-07-16 
00:00:00","Demand":"13550"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-07-23 
00:00:00","Demand":"7971"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-07-30 
00:00:00","Demand":"12442"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-08-06 
00:00:00","Demand":"12960"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-08-13 
00:00:00","Demand":"14106"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-08-20 
00:00:00","Demand":"13543"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-08-27 
00:00:00","Demand":"13570"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-09-03 
00:00:00","Demand":"13506"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-09-10 
00:00:00","Demand":"13914"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-09-17 
00:00:00","Demand":"13241"},{"CPN":"700-42887-01","ExtractDt":"2018-09-24 
00:00:00","Demand":"13449"}]
```

I want to extract only the last Value - Namely 13449. What is the code that i need to write to accomplish this.

Thanks in Advance!`

**Code used**

```
 Sub xmlparsing()
 Dim jstring As String

 With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  .Open "GET", "**INTERNAL COMPANY LINK HERE**", False
    .send
  If .Status <> 200 Then Exit Sub
  jstring = .responseText
   Debug.Print jstring
   End With`
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use InStrRev

```
Mid$(responseText, InStrRev(responseText, ":") + 2, (InStrRev(responseText, "}") - 1) - (InStrRev(responseText, ":") + 2))
```

[InStrRev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function) walks the string from right to left. We know you want the value at the end of the string so this direction is useful. We specify as an argument the character to find. The overall string is the `responseText`.

The first character to find is `":"`, from right to left. This will be where you have `:"13449"}]`. Offset from this + 2 to get the actual start of the value you want, in this case the `1` in `13449`.

Same logic to determine end point of string. I use `"}"` as end point then make an adjustment to move forward to the numbers. [`Mid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) allows you to specify a string, start point and number of characters. I pass the arguments to extract the required string to `Mid`. I used typed functions (with the `$` at the end) as more efficient when working with strings.

Comment: That Worked like a Charm!! Thanks QHarr. If possible could you guide me on how this works, so that i can use it for future reference.

Comment: Thanks QHarr for the detailed explanation, that really helps to use it for future requriements!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact, that you have already parsed the XML to string, then the easiest fact is to try to slice the string. To see how it works, put the string from `.responseText` to A1 range and run this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim responseText As String
    responseText = Range("A1")

    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Split(responseText, "Demand"":""")
    Debug.Print Left(myArr(UBound(myArr)), Len(myArr(UBound(myArr))) - 4)

End Sub
```

What it does is to split the string into array by the word `Demand":"` and to take anything but the last 4 characters of the last unit of the array.

Comment: you beat me to my preferred method!

Comment: @QHarr - to be honest, string slicing is not the best solution here. Serialization of the JSON (although the OP claims it is XML) and accessing the value of the last property would be a way more better solution.

Comment: Sounds likely. The string provided isn’t valid JSON, I think, though so I would still go with split method in this case.

Comment: @QHarr - probably I would do the same. Unless I have time to make it a valid JSON and still serialize it.

Comment: @Vityata I'm going with Qharr's suggestion as the Last demand value can be any number from 1 to Million. In my case i believe it is better that i extract data relative to the position of the characters ":" and "}" to capture this variance.