# Using VBA to find the exchange rate on a specific date with API Norges Bank

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I would like to use VBA to retrieve foreign exchange rates on specific dates useing the API from Norges Bank.

I tried to modify a code I have used before to retrive data from another API, but I'm not able not make it work unfortunately. I have been able to get the API itself to retrive the information I want in a browser, but I would like a VBA code where I'm able to retrive these exchange rates automatically.

In the code below I'm trying to find the exchange rate for XXX/NOK on a specific date.

```
Public Function FX(FXdate As String, FXcurrency As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, thirdVal As String
    firstVal = "https://data.norges-bank.no/api/data/EXR/B."
    secondVal = ".NOK.SP?format=sdmx-json&startPeriod="
    thirdVal = "&endPeriod="
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & secondVal & thirdVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """observations""*""([0-9])""": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetCurrency = CDbl(tmpVal)
 End Function
```

If I for example want the SEK/NOK on the 2nd of January 2018 the raw data API returns the data below. In this example I would like the VBA to return the value after "observations" which in this case is "99.46".

```
{"header":{"id":"64ffd01684ad7f51ab197c573027a05f","prepared":"2018-09-28T09:33:13","test":false,"sender":{"id":"NB"},"receiver":{"id":"ANONYMOUS"}},"dataSets":[{"action":"Information","series":{"0:0:0:0":{"attributes":[0,0,0,0],"observations":{"0":["99.46"]}}}}],"structure":{"name":"Exchange rates","description":"Norges Bank exchange rate statistics","dimensions":{"dataset":[],"series":[{"id":"FREQ","name":"Frequency","description":"The time interval at which observations occur over a given time period.","keyPosition":0,"role":null,"values":[{"id":"B","name":"Business"}]},{"id":"BASE_CUR","name":"Base Currency","description":"The first currency in a currency pair quotation. Also known as the transaction currency.","keyPosition":1,"role":null,"values":[{"id":"SEK","name":"Swedish krona"}]},{"id":"QUOTE_CUR","name":"Quote Currency","description":"The second currency in a currency quote pair. Also known as counter currency.","keyPosition":2,"role":null,"values":[{"id":"NOK","name":"Norwegian krone"}]},{"id":"TENOR","name":"Tenor","description":"The amount of time left for the repayment of a loan or until a financial contract expires.","keyPosition":3,"role":null,"values":[{"id":"SP","name":"Spot"}]}],"observation":[{"id":"TIME_PERIOD","name":"Time Period","description":"The period of time or point in time to which the measured observation refers.","keyPosition":4,"role":"time","values":[{"start":"2018-01-02T00:00:00","end":"2018-01-02T00:00:00","id":"2018-01-02","name":"2018-01-02"}]}]},"attributes":{"dataset":[],"series":[{"id":"DECIMALS","name":"Decimals","description":"The number of digits to the right of a decimal point.","role":null,"values":[{"id":"2","name":"2"}]},{"id":"CALCULATED","name":"Calculated","description":"Indicates if the value is calculated or an actual observation.","role":null,"values":[{"id":"false","name":"false"}]},{"id":"UNIT_MULT","name":"Unit Multiplier","description":"Exponent in base 10 specified so that multiplying the observation numeric values by 10^UNIT_MULT gives a value expressed in the UNIT.","role":null,"values":[{"id":"2","name":"Hundreds"}]},{"id":"COLLECTION","name":"Collection Indicator","description":"Dates or periods during which the observations have been collected.","role":null,"values":[{"id":"C","name":"ECB concertation time 14:15 CET"}]}],"observation":[]}}}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide an example string you are using with the API direct that is working please?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if you go to the link below you will see the output which is in my second code-insertion above: https://data.norges-bank.no/api/data/EXR/B.SEK.NOK.SP?format=sdmx-json&startPeriod=2018-01-02&endPeriod=2018-01-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Making the API call:**

Here is how you can make the API call with a function and use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to get the result. I would have probably used Split myself, to extract the item from the response text, but that has been demonstrated in the answer already given so I will show you JSON parsing instead. I have added an additional header to hopefully mitigate against cached results being served by the browser.

You could move the JSON parsing part into the function but I prefer to demonstrate separately.

You weren't showing the concatenation of values into the URL string for the API call.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    'https://data.norges-bank.no/api/data/EXR/B.SEK.NOK.SP?format=sdmx-json&startPeriod=2018-01-02&endPeriod=2018-01-02
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(FX_json("2018-01-02", "SEK"))
    Debug.Print json("dataSets")(1)("series")("0:0:0:0")("observations")("0")(1)
End Sub

Public Function FX_json(ByVal FXdate As String, ByVal FXcurrency As String) As String
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, thirdVal As String, url As String
    firstVal = "https://data.norges-bank.no/api/data/EXR/B."
    secondVal = ".NOK.SP?format=sdmx-json&startPeriod="
    thirdVal = "&endPeriod="
    url = firstVal & FXcurrency & secondVal & FXdate & thirdVal & FXdate
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")       
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        FX_json = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

---

**JSON treeview:**

Here is a visual of the JSON tree path to the item of interest

[image]

---

**References:**

After downloading and adding JSONConverter.bas to your project go to VBE > Tools >References and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: That VBA JSON library is wonderful, and I would argue a lot easier than doing string splitting. I always use it in any of my VBA projects that use an API returning JSON.

Comment: @zak It is very useful and I like using it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole question could be translated to *How to slice a string?* . There are probably 20+ different ways to do it. From serialization and looping through the correct property to using search(), find(), left, right and splitting.

So, this is simply one of the methods - imagine that you have the whole input string in a given range in excel like this:

[image]

Then you need to get the data between `observations":{"0":["` and the next `"`.

This is achieved, if you split the string to an array by the first delimeter and you take the second part of it. Then split again by `"` and take the first part:

Not very prone with some hard coding, but it should work:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputTxt As String
    inputTxt = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    inputTxt = Split(inputTxt, "observations"":{""0"":[""")(1)
    inputTxt = Split(inputTxt, """")(0)
    Debug.Print inputTxt

End Sub
```

Similar problem:

- [Parsing XML Response in VBA and extracting only last data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537836/parsing-xml-response-in-vba-and-extracting-only-last-data/52538065#52538065)